# Having trouble after enter "bash -v" command in terminal

Tags: linux, shell, terminal

When i enter `bash -v` command in my terminal, Suddenly all **.bashrc** contents was shown on my screen. After that when i press `Tab` button for auto completion, the output shows me as below:

```html
words[0]=${!ref}${COMP_WORDS[i]}
words[1]=${!ref}${COMP_WORDS[i]}
cword=1
words=("${@:3:2}")
cword="$3"
cur="$3"
cur="$3"
cword="$3"
prev="$3"
words=("${@:3:2}")
 compgen -d -- "$quoted" 
 compgen -f -X "$xspec" -- $quoted 
t/
```

I don not know, how fixed it?

Comment: SO is for programming questions, not questions about using or configuring Linux and its applications. SuperUser.com or unix.stackexchange.com would be better places for questions like this.

Comment: If you use `set -v`, you will turn that mode on; if you use `set +v`, you can turn it off again.  You can also be more verbose about it: `set -o verbose` to turn it on and `set +o verbose` to turn it off again.  Or mix'n'match to suit yourself.  Using `bash -nv new-script.sh` is a way of checking the syntax of `new-script.sh` without executing anything.  It shows you what is being read as it is read.  You can omit the `-v` and you won't see the script.  Etc.  So, the `-v` option has its uses — its uses do not include finding out the version of Bash that you're using.

Answer (score 3):

> Man walks into a doctor's office and says "Doc, ya gotta help me, it hurts when I do this". The doctor replies "Well, stop *doing* that".

Not the *best* humour but it raises the question: *why* did you run `bash -v` in the first place?<sup>(a)</sup>

The `-v` flag runs a new invocation of `bash` in verbose mode, where it will output a lot of stuff to assist in debugging. To *stop* it doing that, just exit the `bash` shell that you ran, by typing `exit`.

---

<sup>(a)</sup> It *may* be that you were trying and get the version since many utilities provide `-v` for exactly that purpose. If that was the intent, you should be using `bash --version`.

Comment: Yes. I want to know bash version, but i enter wrong command. Thanks ...